# Ct_param illegal value of 0

Tags: c++, sybase

I'm using sybase 15/12.5 with CS_VERSION_100

When i try to use the ct_param i get an error:

```
An illegal value of 0 was placed in the status field of the CS_DATAFMT structure.
```

But, i create my structure with.

```
CS_DATAFMT datafmt;
strcpy(datafmt.name, "@interface");
datafmt.namelen = 11;
datafmt.datatype=CS_INT_TYPE;
datafmt.maxlength=4;
datafmt.status=CS_INPUTVALUE;
datafmt.locale = NULL;
datafmt.format = 0;
datafmt.scale = -99999;
datafmt.count = 1;
datafmt.usertype=0;

ct_param(command, &datafmt, /* value 300 */, 4, 0)
```

When i do it with a varchar it returns 1 (true), but of course it tells to me that i'm trying to put a varchar param in a place of a int param.
I changed to the last version and now it seems the sybase get the status value from the maxlength.. now it tells to me that the value is 4.
If i change the maxlength to 256 it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, i was compiling for 64 bits, and every sybase program in 64 bits need a -DSYB_LP64.
Then i was compiling with 64 bits but the sybase types were 32 bits, then the sctruct messes up .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting a return variable - according to [The Fine Manual](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-cnarc/cng1110e/ctref/@Generic__BookTextView/47625;hf=0;pt=47755#X)
 you need to use CS_RETURN as the datafmt.status, not CS_INPUTVALUE

Comment: No, its a input, its my first argument in the procedure